# Taking,Saving,Loading Picture on iOS [ xCode]( In English or Portugues)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I started to create a iOS App, and I started to have some troubles.

I have this code:

Taking a picture:

```
- (IBAction)tirarFoto:(id)sender 
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Saving the picture to iOS Photos App:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [self.library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"Relembre" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) 
    {
        if (error!=nil) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];

    _fotoCamera.image = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Ok, so far, so good!

My problem is.
In another viewController I will need to load this picture.
I Have a Core Data in my project.

Can I Save the path(or something that can I load the picture) from the picture I have saved in Photos and save into Core Data, and after load in another view??

I Just need to now the path from picture that I took.

Answer (score 0):

`saveImage:toAlbum:withCompletionBlock:` uses `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:` method, whose block contains assetURL which is exactly what you need.